# Correspond to vs. Correspond with

Tags: grammar, word-usage, synonyms

Is there any significant difference between `Correspond to` and `Correspond with`?

I only mean in the sense of "matching", here, rather than "communication".

I've looked at a few sources, but I can't seem to find a good explanation that makes it clear in which context each form would be used. Some sources suggest that only `Correspond to` is used in the sense of "matching", whereas others suggest `Correspond with` can also be used in that sense (and sometimes also with slightly different meaning).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your question sent me on a pleasant search. A bit more [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/correspond).

**Correspond to** is used when two things are analogous or similar

> ...all of which *correspond to* real numbers...

or agree in amount, position, etc.

> figures and letters on the left in the list below *correspond to* similar figures and letters in the statement of differences...
>   ...events A and B also *correspond to* positions A and B on the train...
>   During the night Lee moved his left up to make his line *correspond to* ours...*

**Correspond with** is used when it means to be in harmony or agreement

> ...a committee was appointed of some from each Quarterly Meeting, to *correspond with* the meeting for sufferers in London...**
>   The empires grew in size and range, and men's ideas grew likewise to *correspond with* these things...

*Personal Memoirs of Ulysses S. Grant (1885)

**[from](http://www.bartleby.com/1/2/5.html) Considerations on the Payment of a Tax laid for Carrying on the War against the Indians (1757)

Comment: Correspond with also, of course, means exchange letters with.

Answer (score -2):

To avoid confusion, use 'correspond with' to indicate written communication with someone and use 'correspond to' to indicate agreement or harmony.

Comment: The way to avoid confusion is to properly understand what the differences are - which is the whole point of the question. (The question is also specifically ***not*** about communication).